# \include & graphicx

Tags: graphics, include, subfiles

I use `\include` and I have the following folder-structure:

```
main.tex
Images/
Subfiles/
    Subfile-1.tex
    Subfile-2.tex
```

Where and how should I put my images, because the code doesn’t compile.

I’ve tried:

```
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{ {Images/} }
```

as well as

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Images/}{../Images/}}
```

Comment: all paths are relative to the working directory from which you run latex, not from the file with `\includegraphics` or  `\documentclass`  so I'd expect a to work, if not show a test file and what error you got,

Comment: you don't ever _need_ to use `\graphicspath` at all. simply use `\includegraphics{Images/someimage.png}`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you try to do should work. I suspect that there is some other problem in the code that you don't show. Here is a concrete example.

Directory structure:

```
main.tex
Images/picture1.png
Images/picture2.png
subfiles/subfile1.tex
subfiles/subfile2.tex
```

Contents of the files:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}
\begin{document}
\include{subfiles/subfile1}
\include{subfiles/subfile2}
\end{document}

% subfiles/subfile1.tex
\section{Chapter 1}
\includegraphics{picture1.png}

% subfiles/subfile2.tex
\section{Chapter 2}
\includegraphics{picture2.png}
```